# How to get XSLT and XPath to output XML in granular HTML manipulation within Symphony CMS

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, symphony-cms

Within Symphony CMS, I want to be able to have an XML document which contains page content (probably using DocBook) and another XML document which is a central acronym/abbreviation repository. This repository, for example could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../utilities/master.xsl"?>
<terminology>
    <abbreviations>
        <term abbr="World Wildlife Fund">WWF</term>
    </abbreviations>
</terminology>
```

An XSL document will then perform transforms with XPath to display the DocBook XML within templates.

For example, within the copy that is output from the DocBook contains the text ‘WWF,’ whenever this occurs, the XSLT and XPath wraps that word with an abbreviation tag with a title using the acronym/abbreviation repository as a resource.

```
<abbr title="World Wildlife Fund">WWF</abbr>
```

The whole setup needs to be extendable enough to have a whole bunch of terms in the repository that can be called upon whenever a certain string of text is seen within the DocBook content.

I have been pointed in the direction of the [HTML Ninja Technique](http://symphony-cms.com/learn/articles/view/html-ninja-technique/) which sounds as though it will provide me with what I need, but the example is pulling in HTML (which seems a bit odd) and does not go into detail about how to perform the kind of manipulation on strings of text I am looking to produce.

It is worth noting, I have been attempting to do this within a master.xsl template in Symphony Utilities. I am happy to be corrected if this won't work within this file.

I am very new to XSLT and XPath, so please don't assume anything of my knowledge when answering this. I am even struggling to wire up the XML and XLS documents at this time. Step-by-step instructions to allow me to produce a proof of concept will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi DigiKev, If i understood the question correctly. You have an XML document (Page content) and another XML document (acronym repository) which looks like 1st code snippet. Then you want to have an XSLT which would transform the XML(Page Content) according to the 2nd Code snippet. ??

Comment: Not exactly Ravish. As I described, I want the page content XML to be output as HTML with an XSLT, but if that page content contains the text WWF, that single text node needs to be wrapped with the abbreviation tag that is titled with the text pulled in from the XML repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I have 3 set of files at same location.

1. Page Document (XML).

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
   <html>
       <span>WWF1</span>
       <span>WWF</span>
       <span>WWF2</span>
   </html>
   ```
2. Acronym Repository (XML)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <terminology>
     <abbreviations>
       <term abbr="World Wildlife Fund 1">WWF1</term>
       <term abbr="World Wildlife Fund 2">WWF2</term>
     </abbreviations>
   </terminology>
   ```
3. Transformer (XSL).

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="html" mode="transform">
            <xsl:with-param name="repository" select="document('repository.xml')/terminology"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>

     <!-- Updated Template Start-->
     <xsl:template match="text()" mode="transform" priority="2.5">
        <xsl:param name="repository" />
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="term" select="$repository/abbreviations/term[contains($this,./text())]" />
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="count($term) > 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., $term/text())"/>
              <xsl:variable name="termTitle" select="$term/@abbr" />
              <abbr title="{$termTitle}"><xsl:value-of select="$term/text()"/></abbr>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($this, $term/text())"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
           </xsl:otherwise> 
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
      <!-- Updated Template Stop-->

      <xsl:template match="node()" mode="transform" priority="2">
         <xsl:param name="repository" />
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="transform">
               <xsl:with-param name="repository" select="$repository"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

The transformer file would give an output like the following.

```
<html>
  <span><abbr title="World Wildlife Fund 1">WWF1</abbr></span>
  <span>WWF</span>
  <span><abbr title="World Wildlife Fund 2">WWF2</abbr></span>
</html>
```

You can scale the acronym by simply adding another  node.

The XSLT need not be changed.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Ravish, thank you so much for this. I haven't been able to try it out fully yet as my host was preventing loopback requests to the same domain as it was a shared server. I am now upgrading to VPS and will try this in Symphony shortly once I am setup again.

Comment: Okay, Ravish I have a new server which allows loopback requests. I still am unable to get this working yet. My site is at http://k-rapley.co.uk/ and can be debugged on this page using Symphony’s processing error page. My terminology.xml and pages.xml are located in /workspace/data-sources/ and are attached to the template as can be seen at http://k-rapley.co.uk/?debug

Comment: I am unable to see the entire master.xsl. There is some syntax errors in it. If possible you can make it available or post it here. So that the errors can be removed.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please remove the xsl linkage from the terminology.xml. It should be linked only with the pages.xml.

Comment: I have linked the pages.xml to the master.xsl, but removed it from terminology.xml.

Comment: Please note that master.xsl and terminology.xml are not at same location. Hence you need to use document(../data-sources/terminology.xml).
Also, I have changed the 2nd <xsl:template> to check any contained string. Please update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13376/discussion-between-ravish-and-digikev)